# How to cluster similar documents based on their keywords?

Tags: r, nlp, cluster-analysis, document, k-means

I'm working on a document clustering project in R. I have 100 pages, and for each pages I have extracted the keywords. Now, I would like to cluster the pages in a way that the same pages, with the same concept, fall into the same cluster.

I have found a lots of document clustering codes, which just focused on the keywords clustering not the page clustering. Any suggestion or idea for my problem?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Should be pretty straight forward. There's lost of clustering libraries in R. How exactly you do it depends on the shape of your data. If you could give us an example, that would help

Comment: **Show some effort** to implement this. Do not expect us to do your job, only to assist with a specific issue that you have in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Getting Started with Latent Dirichlet Allocation using RTextTools + topicmodels](http://www.rtexttools.com/blog/getting-started-with-latent-dirichlet-allocation-using-rtexttools-topicmodels)

If you extract the keywords from a page to cluster the pages you kind of based on the keywords. What do you expect from page clustering?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm really new in text retrieval community. I have 100 pages which each single page is 3 lines and is a summary of a book. I want to cluster(group) those pages which are similar to each other (so similar books would be clusterd). This Topic modeling was very nice but is I think it can not be considered as my solution strategy.

Comment: Sounds interesting, let me know if you found it.